# Serverless lambda - Function not executing completely

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, bulkinsert, serverless

I'm using serverless with nodejs. I have lambda function which have around 6 API in it.
All APIs are working except one. But this non-working api is working fine in local serverless offline. After deployment in server, then it is behaving delayed. 
Here is skeleton of what I did in api function

```
let rec_list = await db.sequelize.query(query).spread(rec_list => { return rec_list; }).catch((e)=>{
console.log("error");
    throw e;
})

let rec_list2= rec_list .map((rec_list_sub) => {
//some assignment here
//let new_var = {}; // just assignment - no db operation
return new_var;
});


let resultArr = await Promise.all(rec_list2).then((result) => {

      return result;
     }).catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });

let tem_list = await db.mymodel.bulkCreate(resultArr).then(function (li) {
      selectedIds = li.map(({ id }) => {

        return {
          reqId: id,
          description: 'sent',
          status: 0
          }
      });
      return li;
    }).catch(function (err) {
      throw err;
    });
  //send fcm push
//triggering push notification to user
  fcm_send_msg("success", "body-message-here",["fdsfdsfdsf-device-id"]); //*--> Push notification is not triggered. When i hit any of api from this same lambda function, then previously called apis' push notification triggered.*
```

If I place push notification function call which is aysnc (tried with/without await) before bulkcreate call, then it is working but bulk create delayed.

Execution time for lambda function is 6 sec but it took 108ms only. Memory allocated 1024mb but 120mb only used.

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue but its weird to see mixing Promise.then usage with async await usage

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a *lot* of assumptions, so if I am totally off base let me know and I will delete this answer.  I assume your lambda is running in a VPC since it is accessing a database.  And from your question I am understanding you to be saying that when the call "bulkCreate" happens before the call to "fcm_send_msg" then you are experiencing the issue, but when the call the "fcm_send_msg" happens before the call to "bulkCreate" then you get the notification, but the bulk create is still delayed.

I suspect you may have a permission issue.  Lambda uses an ephemeral port range for calls, so you will want to be sure your security groups and NACLs allow the full ephemeral port range from which Lambda may originate the calls.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports:

> AWS Lambda functions use ports 1024-65535.

You can check the CloudWatch logs for the lambda (from monitoring) to see what it is doing, and if you see things in the logs that seem like something failed and it is retrying it could very well indicate that the calls are being blocked due to security groups or NACLs that don't allow the communication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In cloudwatch log, there is no error thrown. There is only data related to request , responses, and console logs whatever i added.